# A projectile is shot straight up from (non-rotating) Earth's surface at a speed of 10,000 km/h. How "high" does it go (to 2 s.f, in m)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile

What is wrong with my work? It continuously gives me an incorrect error, but I can't identify the step at which I made a mistake. My work is shown as follows:

let the height be h

radius of earth , r = 6.371 * 10^6 m

value of accelration due to gravity , g' = 0.1 * g

G * mass of earth /( r + h)^2 = 0.1 * g

6.67 * 10^-11 * 5.98 * 10^24 /(6.371 * 10^6 + h ) = 0.98

h = 1.38 * 10^7 m

the height above the earth is 1.38 * 10^7 m

the speed of the orbiting satellite , v = sqrt( G * M /( r + h))

v = sqrt ( 6.67 * 10^-11 * 5.98 * 10^24 / ( 6.371 * 10^6 + 1.38 * 10^7))

v = 4446.82 m/s

the speed of the orbiting satellite is 4446.82 m/s = 4.446 km/s

Are there any obvious problems with this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use energy because the value of $g$ varies with height.

So something like $\frac 12 m v^2 - \frac{GMm}{R} = 0 - \frac{GMm}{R+h}$